# Wordpress admin area, best action to hook to add fixed popup

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I am researching the best action to hook with in the Wordpress admin area in order to add essentially a fixed position block that is stuck to the right side of the screen on EVERY admin page.

The aim of this is to provide a popup on click where it will list some shortcodes/available options. The code will be added to a plugin.

I've had a look and can see the following are possibilities but which would be the best for the outcome I desire?

- admin_footer
- admin_init
- admin_notices

I believe the answer to this question would be best accepted if it explains the general action to use to display on all pages. And circumstances that may cause an exception (as I believe the common use is admin_notices but this is perhaps an exception?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in listing the possibilities of hooks in your answer, however, they do each have "standard" use cases of which one would be preferred to use over another. Please see the below:

**Action:** admin_notices

The action of `admin_notices` refers directly to the html section above the main content of an admin page. For example above the title box on a page/post editor.

Due to the placement of the HTML you would be restricted in what styling you would be able to achieve as the surrounding `<div>` elements could causes issues with absolute and fixed positioning.

It's also an "industry standard" to reserve this action for only displaying plugin/theme related *notices* hence the name admin_notices. Things such as new Wordpress updates, Plugin Configuration Notices, or even useful tips/instructions for a theme/plugin upon activation.

**Action:** admin_footer

You're probably looking to use the `admin_footer` action as it allows much more freedom for the styling as there is less constricting `<div>` elements surrounding it.

The `admin_footer` action is also not reserved for anything in particular unlike the `admin_notices`. And therefore would be better fit for your purpose as your addition is not a notice but more of a permanent feature whereas notices tend to me temporary.

**Additional Information**

Now you've chosen your appropriate action for your function, you'll need to presumably load CSS files and possibly JS files to style your fixed popup.

To do so you will need to make use of the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action ([More info here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)).

You can also limit the appearance of your fixed popup by checking the current screen you are on and restricting the appearance based off of the returned value. See below:

```
$current_screen = get_current_screen();
if ( $current_screen->post_type == '' || $current_screen->base != 'post' ) {
    return 'html';
}
```

Comment: Ive requested an edit to your answer once approved will mark as correct